# How to Encrypt and Decrypt Data in SQL Server 2008 r2 from C#?

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2008-r2, cryptography, aes

Hi I am able to do Encryption and Decryption for a specified string and Saving in to the database. But i want to search that Data.But it is not possible to search data for an Encrypted column. There is any Way to that. In front i am using AES, the below method is used for encryption.

```
  private string Encrypt(string Text)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "abcdef@123";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Text);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                Text = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return Text;
    }
```

the below method is used for Decryption

```
     private string Decrypt(string Text)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "abcdef@123";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Text);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return Text;
    }
```

can anybody help me based on this..,

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is - that's part of the point of encryption in a round-about way.

If the string has certain characteristics which are searched on, such as a name embedded in it for example, you could calculate the SOUNDEX value of the name and store that in a separate column. You could then do a search based on the soundex value of the name, which would cut down on the number of rows returned each of which you then decrypt and do your search on. That was at least you won't have to pull down the whole table.
Of course, doing that may be a security loophole....

Cheers -

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to create SQL CLR Database Project  and created one function with

Decryption logic and call in SQL Query. you will able to search encrypted data.